# Change ItemsSource of DataGrid at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm very new to WPF, so sorry if I'm not quite clear...

I have a UserControl, that contains a DataGrid. I have a ViewModel that contains two properties of type List<>, 'ListA' and 'ListB'. I create inside the UserControl a DataContext from the ViewModel. The DataGrid inside the UserControl is supposed to display the content of one of the two lists, depending on input.

My problem is that I don't know how to change the list displayed by the DataGrid at runtime, according to user inputs.

The two ways I know to link a graphical element to some data is in the .xaml code, with `Content="{Binding ListA"}`, which is not appropriate because it hardcodes the list to display, so I can't change it. The other option I could imagine would be to say, in the CodeBehind, something like `TheDataGrid.ItemsSource=DataContext.ListA`. That way, I could dynamically set another list to the DataGrid. The problem is that I can't seem to access the data of the DataContext that way in the code behind.

Comment: Create a third property `ListToDisplay` with change notification that either holds the value of ListA or ListB.

Comment: Alternatively create a DataGrid Style that changes the Binding in a DataTrigger.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I thought about this option. My problem here is that I don't know how to change the state of the ViewModel (i.e. switch from ListToDisplay = ListA to ListToDisplay = ListB)  when I click a button. I instanciate my viewmodel with `this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();`, but I don't know how to access its public methods, since DataContext.SwapLists() is not accessible.

Comment: You would typically bind your Button to an ICommand property in your view model, which can call a method in the view model.

Comment: Oh ok. I'll try that.